# How to list all messages in Outlook search

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Does anyone know if there is a way to list all messsages from current and subfolders in Outlook 2013?  I want to get everything from a folder and all of its subfolders and then be able to put them in date order.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next to the search box you can select subfolders which will search through current and subfolders.

In the search box, use `%` as a wild card.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Didn't know that % was wildcard character.